# Using contains in Linq query produces error

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a pretty straight forward query that is producing this error at runtime: Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method.

The query is supposed to find only the categories that have transfers assigned to them. The transfers can be listed in several categories so there is no table relationship. The Categoryidhash contains data like "7~34~25~42~47". I just realized while writing this that searching for '7' will return multiple results, "7" & '47' Etc. Thats ok i'll just change id's to all double digits. meanwhile...

How can I fix this?

```
    Private Function GetCategoryList() As List(Of Category)
    Dim lst As List(Of Category) = New List(Of Category)

    Using db As New IPCDataDataContext

        lst = (From c In db.Categories
              From t In db.Transfers
              Where t.CategoryIDhash.Contains(c.ID.ToString)
              Select c).ToList()
        Return lst
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: *"I just realized while writing this that searching for '7' will return multiple results, "7" & '47' Etc. Thats ok i'll just change id's to all double digits."* **That in itself is an indication that you are going about this the wrong way.** The normal approach is to make a join, and store each (in your case) category ID in a separate table which has a foreign key relationship to the (looks like in your case) transfers table. What if you need more than 99 categories at some future point? I don't know exactly how to write Linq-to-SQL code for that but you really should look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception means that `Contains` only accepts arguments that can be converted to fixed variable in SQL. So something like `Where t.CategoryIDhash.Contains(someVariable.ToString)` would be possible, because `someVariable.ToString` can be evaluated client-side.

I don't really understand this restriction, because in SQL it is perfectly possible to use a `LIKE` clause with a string that is built in the SQL statement itself. This is demonstrated by the statement that fixes your problem:

```vb
lst = (From c In db.Categories
      From t In db.Transfers
      Where SqlMethods.Like(t.CategoryIDhash, "%" + c.ID.ToString "%")
      Select c).ToList()
```

This generates (and executes) SQL like

```sql
...
WHERE [t1].[CategoryIDhash] LIKE (@p0 + (CONVERT(NVarChar,[t0].[ID]))) + @p1
```

(where `@p0` and `@p1` are the `%` characters.

Although you could do this, I wonder if you're on the right track by using this `CategoryIDhash`. I think you should convert it to a FK relationship (if it's in your hands to modify the database).

Comment: Thank you @Gert for the explanation, However it didn't produce the results I was looking for, I received dupes of empty categories. How can I properly create the relationship between these two tables so I can have the transfers exist in several categories?

Comment: What do you mean by _dupes of empty categories_? I think you should also check `&& t.CategoryIDhash.Length > 0`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have distinct in the query and it was returning multiples. I understand that this approach may not be the best way to handle this situation as you pointed out, but is a third table linking the two tables the better approach? It's going to be a huge table when it's all said and done.

Comment: A linking table is undoubtedly better. No decent database is scared off by a couple of millions of records.